# How to whitelist programmatically-generated PHP files in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

I'm generating some PHP code programmatically, which I want to test through PHPUnit.

Code is generated as the test cases require it, and it is then saved in php files in a whitelisted folder.

When PHPUnit finishes running, the files are left in that folder so that I can check the code coverage on them.

However, in my PHPUnit's bootstrap I am emptying that folder, so that previous PHPUnit executions won't affect the result of the execution just launched.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    bootstrap="./test/bootstrap.php"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnError="true"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="TestSuite">
            <directory>./test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src-generated/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

PHPUnit complains that the folder is empty.

```
Error: Incorrect whitelist config, no code coverage will be generated.
```

Is there a way to whitelist files as they are generated? Is there a way to add them dynamically or tell PHPUnit to cover any file encountered regardless of the path?

The paths are correct, test all run correctly, except that I get no code coverage.

Than you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe if you use the @coversNothing annotation in the generated files it will be covered and so you will not need the white listing.